# How to attach a variable/value on onclick in href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been studying Web and PhoneGap recently and I am stuck at this problem. I have a sqlite db. I was able to query the necessary data I need. However, I want to pop an alert in each element generated from the query.

```
html += '<a href="#" class="category-btn" title="All" rel="external" onclick="alert(\'app.listDisplay: \' );">'+ res.rows.item(i).name  +'</a>';
```

The onclick successfully pops an alert, but I want to show my the value `res.rows.item(i).name` in my alert. How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Concatenating also string inside that JavaScript (assuming you don't need to escape res.rows.item(i).name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code works (doesn't show errors in developer tools as firebug), try with the following:

```
html += '<a href="#" class="category-btn" title="All" rel="external" onclick="alert(\'app.listDisplay:' + res.rows.item(i).name + ' \' );">'+ res.rows.item(i).name  +'</a>';
```